# eslint no-unused-vars varIgnorePattern not working

Tags: javascript, eslint

I am using slick.js jquery plugin inside requireJS. Thus in order to make the plugin available I have to `require` it, which is introducing an

> 'slick' is defined but never used  no-unused-vars

error from eslint. Here is the code

```
define(['jquery', 'slick'], function($, slick) {
    'use strict';

    $.widget("mage.promobanner", {
        _addSlider: function(self) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(self.element).slick(self.options);
            }, 2000);
        }
    });
    return $.mage.promobanner;
});
```

I have tried creating an exception for this variable per the [`varsIgnorePattern` documentation](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#varsignorepattern)

`/*eslint no-unused-vars: ["error", { "varsIgnorePattern": "slick" }]*/`

however the error persists. Is there something wrong with the ignore pattern I have created? Seems like a no-brainer regex: *exact match*!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The correct exception uses [`argsIgnorePattern`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#argsignorepattern), not [`varsIgnorePattern`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-unused-vars#varsignorepattern).

> ### varsIgnorePattern
>
> The `varsIgnorePattern` option specifies exceptions not to check for usage: variables whose names match a regexp pattern.

> ### argsIgnorePattern
>
> The `argsIgnorePattern` option specifies exceptions not to check for usage: arguments whose names match a regexp pattern.

So use:

```js
/* eslint no-unused-vars: [ "error", { "argsIgnorePattern": "slick" } ] */
```